# Paging Error: The method 'Skip' is only supported for sorted input in LINQ to Entities. The method 'OrderBy' must be called before the method 'Skip'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have this following codes. I did not use a sorting just with the filtering or searching of information. I did not use skip method also. Please see codes below.

```
public ActionResult Index(string currentFilter=null, string search=null, string searchBy=null, int? page=1)
    {
        var student = from d in db.Student_vw
                      where d.is_active == true
                      select d;
        if (searchBy == "default")
        {
            student = student.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID_Number);
        }

        //searching of an item
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            student = student.Where(x => x.ID_Number.Contains(search) || x.student_fname.Contains(search)
                || x.student_lname.Contains(search) || x.section_name.Contains(search) || x.course_name.Contains(search)
                || x.student_address.Contains(search) || x.batch_name.Contains(search) || x.adviser_fname.Contains(search) || x.adviser_lname.Contains(search) || x.student_email_add.Contains(search));
        }
        else {
            student = student.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID_Number);
        }
        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = search;

        int pageSize = 25;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        var returnMe = student.ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

        return View(returnMe);
    }
```

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: ToPagedList uses Skip, you need to order your results first as the exception message says.

Answer (score 1):

in your code, when search having value, students not ordered. do as below

```
public ActionResult Index(string currentFilter=null, string search=null, string searchBy=null, int? page=1)
    {
        var student = from d in db.Student_vw
                      where d.is_active == true
                      select d;
        //if (searchBy == "default")
        //{
        //    student = student.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID_Number);
        //}

        //searching of an item
        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            student = student.Where(x => x.ID_Number.Contains(search) || x.student_fname.Contains(search)
                || x.student_lname.Contains(search) || x.section_name.Contains(search) || x.course_name.Contains(search)
                || x.student_address.Contains(search) || x.batch_name.Contains(search) || x.adviser_fname.Contains(search) || x.adviser_lname.Contains(search) || x.student_email_add.Contains(search));
        }
        //else {
        //    student = student.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID_Number);
        //}
        ViewBag.CurrentFilter = search;

        int pageSize = 25;
        int pageNumber = (page ?? 1);

        var returnMe = student.OrderByDescending(x => x.ID_Number).ToPagedList(pageNumber, pageSize);

        return View(returnMe);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

@Jen- You need to use OrderBy before student.ToPageList(pageNumber, pageSize)

Answer (score 0):

SQL doesn't guarantee the order of results unless you give it an order by, so using Take or Skip (which PagedList does internally) without an order by doesn't make any logical sense and in theory could give you totally different results each time.

The way you have written your logic you can fall through without every hitting on of the order by statements.